# Kubernetes cluster get-credentials returning error on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, gcloud

I am on Windows 10 and after I set up my Kubernetes cluster on the Google Console called ticketing-dev, I did gcloud init on the command line. When I type this into my command line:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ticketing-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'U:\\'
```

Could you please suggest how I can fix this problem? I tried to search for solutions online but cant find anything.

Comment: The command updates the machine's kube config file. It uses the machine's `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to determine where the files is. I suspect (!) your machine's `KUBECONFIG` environment variable is either set to `U:` or it's unset and, for some unknown reason, defaulting there. Can you try determining the value of `KUBECONFIG`? Perhaps try setting the variable to a known good location and then running the `gcloud` command again. Note this will create a new kube config file. You should then be able to use `kubectl`

Comment: I set the KUBECONFIG environment variable with $Env:KUBECONFIG="$Env:KUBECONFIG;$HOME\.kube\config but it is still returning the same error

Comment: Hmmm. Can you try something even simpler for me: `$env:KUBECONFIG = "$HOME"`. This avoids including the possibly incorrect existing value. If that doesn't work, I'm outta ideas.

Comment: Tried, doesnt work unfortunately..

Comment: Hopefully someone who uses Windows can help. I'm intrigued. Perhaps try: (1)  cmd.exe instead of PowerShell? (2) `$env:KUBECONFIG = "c:\" instead of `$HOME`?

Comment: Hmmm.... You're not the first. Though these were both closed without resolution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160716449; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153154726; This is "assigned" but unresolved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157713325

Comment: Which version Cloud SDK your installed on win10? My Cloud SDK version is Google Cloud SDK 324.0.0( beta 2021.01.19 bq 2.0.64 core 2021.01.19 gsutil 4.57 kubectl 1.17.14), and run that command without any error.